# VBA Create table: Syntax error with table header table

Tags: excel, vba

I have a code that creates a table that works just fine, but I realized that I forgot to acknowledge that my range already has table headers. When I change the code by adding `xlYes` then I get an "expected: named parameter" error.

This code works in the macro
`RD.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=xlSrcRange, Source:=tbl).Name = "Bucket_Info"`

This code does not work
`RD.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=xlSrcRange, Source:=tbl, , xlYes).Name = "Bucket_Info"`

where is the error?

Comment: Do you understand what a [named parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/understanding-named-arguments-and-optional-arguments) is? The name of the parameter in question is `XlListObjectHasHeaders`, as shown in the [`ListObjects.Add`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.listobjects.add) docs.

Comment: `SourceType:=xlSrcRange, Source:=tbl, XlListObjectHasHeaders:=xlYes`